X-ray diffraction: coherence of the radiation source
In diffraction/interference processes I've always thought that coherence is an important condition for the source. If I well understand this is also why we choose punctiform sources of light which come from the same wave front of a primary source, for example.
Now, in the setting of an X-ray diffraction experiment I don't find all this conditions. Why if the source is both spatially and temporally incoherent we don't see an average of the intensity?

Because each photon happily diffracts all by itself. Same as with visible light and a diffraction grating.

@JonCuster But why in the double slit experiment you try to use a primary source which is the most punctiform possible in order to reduce incoherence? With incoherence sources you don't see a pattern

A spatially distributed source blurs the diffraction pattern, yes. But this is not an issue of spatial coherence but spatial extent.

@JonCuster thanks. if it's not decoherence the reason of the blurs by a big souce, what is?

Sadly, "coherence" is a bit overloaded as a term. Coming from a small spot size (which reduces blur) does not mean that there is any phase relationship between individual photons (like in a laser).

@JonCuster do you know some reference where I can find information about it?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Typical coherence lengths of X-ray or neutron beams are of the order of $10$ nm (see, for example, Leroy, Marie-Alix, et al. Tunnel-mediated coupling between antiferromagnetic thin films. Physical Review B, 2014, 90.3: 035432.)
For quasi-monochromatic beams, the coherence time $\tau$ can be estimated from the spectral width $\Delta k$ and the phase velocity $v_p$ from the relation
$$
\tau \geq \frac{1}{2 \Delta k v_p}
$$
(see de Haan, V. (2007). Coherence Approach to Neutron Propagation in SpinEcho Instruments. Delft University of Technology, Delft.)

Thanks! And what about temporal coherence?

It is mainly about the interaction of the photons of the exposure source with the subatomic particles of the obstacle. This is very obvious for X-ray diffraction on crystal structures.
For a sharp diffraction image - which reveals the structure of the crystal lattice - it is only important that the radiation is monochromatic. From which point of the source and at what time the photons are emitted, on the other hand, is irrelevant. In this respect, it is also not possible to speak of a waveform of the emitted radiation. After interaction with the crystal lattice, however, the magnetic and electric field components of the photons are spatially aligned and the intensity of the radiation on the observation screen is generated by the distribution of the atoms and molecules of the lattice.
If one were to extend this observation to a slit and visible light, one could come to the conclusion that the interaction of the surface electrons of the slit with the photons of the light source could also lead to the intensity distribution on the observation screen. The link to this would be phonon excitations in the material of the obstacle. Since we are not dealing with a crystal lattice here, but the photons of the visible light only interact with the electrons of the outer orbitals or the valence electrons, a point-shaped light source is useful. The wider the light beam, the more blurred the phonon excitations and the intensity distribution.

Thanks! But why for a crystal i can't translate what you say for visible light? Is the wavelenght the difference between the requirements of the sources? A deeper insight on electron motion in the two cases might be helpful, I think

With crystals, you are examining volume, so a broad (quasi-parallel) beam of X-ray photons is ok. With a narrow slit, you generate the phonons by excitation at the immediate edge of the slit using a narrowly focused photon beam. Photons hitting at a wider angle disturb the phonon generation and the diffraction pattern disappears.
